# wrapping templated function call in another function call

Tags: c++, c++20

Anyone know if it is possible to do something similar to the following:

```
void my_inner_func(int i, double d, ...) { 
    // do stuff here
}

template <typename Func, typename... Args>
void my_outer_func(Func&& f,Args&&... args){
    // do other stuff here, put this inside loop, etc
    f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

template <typename OuterFunc,typename InnerFunc,typename... Args>
void func(OuterFunc&& outer, InnerFunc&& inner, Args&&...args) {
    outer(std::forward<InnerFunc>(inner),std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Where the calling code might look something like this:

```
func(my_outer_func, my_inner_func, 1, 2.0, ...);
```

The issue that I am running into is that the type of the OuterFunction cannot be deduced. I've tried a bunch of different things including converting func to a functor and making OuterFunc a template template parameter.

Comment: `my_outer_func` needs to be wrapped in a lambda when passing it to `func`. Or it must be a lambda to begin with.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat thanks for your reply. Are you able to elaborate? I tried a few things with lambdas, but couldn't get it to work. Wrapping `my_outer_func` in a lambda still gave me the same errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works if you make `my_outer_func` a function object rather than a function:

```
struct my_outer_func {
    template <typename Func, typename... Args>
    void operator()(Func&& f,Args&&... args) const {
        // do other stuff here, put this inside loop, etc
        f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};
```

Then:

```
func(my_outer_func(), my_inner_func, 1, 2.0);
```

If you don't like the parentheses at the call site, you can remove them if you create a global struct instance instead:

```
struct {
    template <typename Func, typename... Args>
    void operator()(Func&& f,Args&&... args) const {
        // do other stuff here, put this inside loop, etc
        f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
} my_outer_func;
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure that I completely understand how this solves the issue but it does work. I guess this must have to do with the order in which the template parameters are deduced at the class/function scope vs the method scope? Anyways thanks!

Comment: My solution (and the lambda solution) works because `my_outer_func` is now a non-template.  The template is only found when you "call" it, at which point the arguments are known and the template parameters are deduced.

Comment: @JacobMerson Your original code didn't work because `my_outer_func` didn't have a type until template arguments are substituted into it, but a type is needed to pass it into another function. Template lambdas (or structs with templated `operator()`, which are the same) don't have this limitation, because the lambda itself has a specific type, regardless of its templated `operator()`.

Comment: Thanks. I just realized that as I was staring at it. This makes a ton of sense now that I see how it works.

Answer (score 3):

`my_outer_func` needs to be wrapped in a lambda when passing it to `func`:

```
func([](auto &&... params){my_outer_func(decltype(params)(params)...);}, my_inner_func, 1, 2.0);
```

Where `decltype(params)(params)` is equivalent to `std::forward<decltype(params)>(params)`, but with less typing.

Or, `my_outer_func` can itself be a lambda:

```
auto my_outer_func = []<typename Func, typename... Args>(Func&& f,Args&&... args)
{
    f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
};
```

Explicit template parameters in a lambda are a C++20 feature. Pre-C++20 you'd have to use `auto`, like in the first example.

Comment: I accepted the other answer because I saw that one first, but this is equally helpful. Again, thanks so much!